# SQL Question - What is wrong with my WHERE clause

Tags: sql, boolean-algebra

It's been a few years since I had to use SQL and I had to write a query – but I got results that I didn't expect. I've spent so many hours looking at it that I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but, when I run this below, my query is returning `RateCode` values other than what is in my `WHERE` statement.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like its a basic enough query (and I'm starting to panic that I've lost my skill)

```
SELECT
    cs.Acct AS Site,
    cs.Addr1 AS Address,
    cs.City,
    cs.State,
    m.TypeDescr AS Service,
    se.Quantity,
    se.SvcCode,
    se.SvcDescr,
    sf.FreqDescr AS Frequency,
    se.SvcId, 
    se.StartDate,
    se.EndDate,
    sr.ReasonDescr AS Reason,
    svr.RateCode,  
    svr.StartDate AS RateStartDate,
    svr.EndDate AS RateEndDate

FROM
    wiSvcEquipment AS se
    LEFT JOIN wiCustSite    AS cs  ON cs.SiteId    = se.SiteId
    LEFT JOIN wiMaterial    AS m   ON m.MatSubType = se.MatSubType
    LEFT JOIN wiSvcReason   AS sr  ON sr.ReasonID  = se.ReasonID
    LEFT JOIN wiSvcVendRate AS svr ON svr.SvcId    = se.SvcID
    LEFT JOIN wiSvcCustRate as scr ON scr.RateCode = se.RateCode
    LEFT JOIN wiSvcFreq     AS sf  ON sf.FreqID    = se.FreqID

WHERE
    se.CustId = ‘013714’
    OR
    se.CustId = ‘014831’
    AND 
    svr.RateCode IN (
        ‘CHGCMBHAUL’, ‘CHGHAUFLAT’, ‘CHGHAUL2’, ‘CHGHAUL3’,
        ‘CHGHAULCOM’, ‘CHGHAULFE’, ‘CHGHAULING’, ‘CHGHAULMIN’,
        ‘CHGVCMBHAU’, ‘CHGVHAUFLT’, ‘CHGVHAULFE’, ‘CHGVHAULNG’,
        ‘CHGWKDHAUL’, ‘CLIHAUFLAT’, ‘CLIHAULFE’, ‘CLIHAULING’
    ) ;
```

Comment: I assume the `’` characters are because you're using a Mac, and that your actual SQL has normal ASCII single-quotes `'` ?

Comment: Are any of your join fields null? That can give you invalid results

Comment: Anyway, you likely have the precedence of `AND` and `OR` confused. It's best to use explicit groups in parentheses (I've been writing queries SQL by-hand for more than 17 years and I still don't know which logical operators have a higher precedence)

Comment: @Noel How does having `NULL` join values result in "invalid" results? Those are `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operations on non-composite foreign-keys - looks fine to me.

Comment: Having just checked the SQL spec, apparently `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`. So there's your problem.

Comment: Yes, `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` in every programming language I've ever used, as well as in high school algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **se.CustId = ‘013714’** clause is satisfied then no matter what the retcode is this query will return the rows.

Is your intention to use below condition:

```
WHERE
    (se.CustId = ‘013714’
    OR
    se.CustId = ‘014831’)
    AND 
    svr.RateCode IN (
        ‘CHGCMBHAUL’, ‘CHGHAUFLAT’, ‘CHGHAUL2’, ‘CHGHAUL3’,
        ‘CHGHAULCOM’, ‘CHGHAULFE’, ‘CHGHAULING’, ‘CHGHAULMIN’,
        ‘CHGVCMBHAU’, ‘CHGVHAUFLT’, ‘CHGVHAULFE’, ‘CHGVHAULNG’,
        ‘CHGWKDHAUL’, ‘CLIHAUFLAT’, ‘CLIHAULFE’, ‘CLIHAULING’
    ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `WHERE` to use `IN` for both columns:

```
WHERE
    se.CustId IN ( '013714', '014831' )
    AND 
    svr.RateCode IN (
        'CHGCMBHAUL', 'CHGHAUFLAT', 'CHGHAUL2', 'CHGHAUL3',
        'CHGHAULCOM', 'CHGHAULFE', 'CHGHAULING', 'CHGHAULMIN',
        'CHGVCMBHAU', 'CHGVHAUFLT', 'CHGVHAULFE', 'CHGVHAULNG',
        'CHGWKDHAUL', 'CLIHAUFLAT', 'CLIHAULFE', 'CLIHAULING'
    );
```

Or use an explicit logical group:

```
WHERE
    (
        se.CustId = '013714'
        OR
        se.CustId = '014831'
    )
    AND 
    svr.RateCode IN (
        'CHGCMBHAUL', 'CHGHAUFLAT', 'CHGHAUL2', 'CHGHAUL3',
        'CHGHAULCOM', 'CHGHAULFE', 'CHGHAULING', 'CHGHAULMIN',
        'CHGVCMBHAU', 'CHGVHAUFLT', 'CHGVHAULFE', 'CHGVHAULNG',
        'CHGWKDHAUL', 'CLIHAUFLAT', 'CLIHAULFE', 'CLIHAULING'
    );
```

The two clauses above are strictly identical: in SQL the `x IN ( a, b, c )` operator is just syntactic sugar for a series of `( x = a OR x = b OR x = c )` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean

```
(se.CustId = ‘013714’ OR se.CustId = ‘014831’)
```

AND has precedence over OR

Answer (score 1):

I can see three things:

1. You need parentheses -- or better yet -- `IN` for the first condition.
2. conditions on all but the first table in a series of `LEFT JOIN`s should be in the `ON` clause.
3. Your strings have smart quotes, but they should be "straight" single quotes.

So:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM wiSvcEquipment se
     wiCustSite cs 
     ON cs.SiteId = se.SiteId LEFT JOIN
     wiMaterial m  
     ON m.MatSubType = se.MatSubType LEFT JOIN
     wiSvcReason sr 
     ON sr.ReasonID = se.ReasonID AND
            svr.RateCode IN ('CHGCMBHAUL', 'CHGHAUFLAT', 'CHGHAUL2', 'CHGHAUL3',
                             'CHGHAULCOM', 'CHGHAULFE', 'CHGHAULING', 'CHGHAULMIN’,
                             'CHGVCMBHAU', 'CHGVHAUFLT', 'CHGVHAULFE', 'CHGVHAULNG',
                             'CHGWKDHAUL', 'CLIHAUFLA’, 'CLIHAULFE', 'CLIHAULING'
                            ) LEFT JOIN

        LEFT JOIN
     wiSvcVendRate svr
     ON svr.SvcId = se.SvcID LEFT JOIN
     wiSvcCustRate scr
     ON scr.RateCode = se.RateCode LEFT JOIN
     wiSvcFreq sf 
     ON sf.FreqID = se.FreqID
WHERE se.CustId IN ('013714', '014831')
```

Comment: Wouldn't any competent SQL engine generate the same execution-plan for this query compared to the original? i.e. predicates can be in either `JOIN x ON y` and `WHERE y` and still have the same plan if the engine can prove they're equivalent?

Comment: @Dai . . . This has to do with the *semantics* of the query, not the *syntax*.  The logic is different.  A `WHERE` clause on subsequent tables changes the joins to inner joins.